# Displays the currency input form without having to click first

Tags: javascript, html, input, currency

I have a question
I want to display the input form in the currency format, but I have a problem that the input form must be clicked first.

This is my code input HTML

```
<label class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-0">Harga Jual</label>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control currency" id="hargabarang" readonly="readonly"> 
            </div>
```

My code currency

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.currency').maskMoney({prefix:'Rp. ', thousands:'.', decimal:',', precision:0});
})
```

My calculate

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#jumlah").keyup(function(){ 
       var jumlah = parseInt($("#jumlah").val());
       var minimal_jual = $("#minimal_jual").val();
       var minimal_grosir1 = $("#minimal_grosir1").val();
       var minimal_grosir2 = $("#minimal_grosir2").val();
       var minimal_grosir3 = $("#minimal_grosir3").val();
       var harga_jual = $("#harga_jual").val();
       var grosir1 = $("#grosir1").val();
       var grosir2 = $("#grosir2").val();
       var grosir3 = $("#grosir3").val();
       var satuan_jual = $("#satuan_jual").val();
       var satuan_grosir1 = $("#satuan_grosir1").val();
       var satuan_grosir2 = $("#satuan_grosir2").val();
       var satuan_grosir3 = $("#satuan_grosir3").val();

   if (jumlah < minimal_grosir1) {
     var satuan = satuan_jual;
   } else if(jumlah >= minimal_grosir1 && jumlah < minimal_grosir2) {
     var satuan = satuan_grosir1;
   } else if(jumlah >= minimal_grosir2 && jumlah < minimal_grosir3) {
     var satuan = satuan_grosir2;
   } else if(jumlah >= minimal_grosir3) {
     var satuan = satuan_grosir3;
   };

   if (jumlah < minimal_grosir1) {
     var harga = harga_jual;
   } else if(jumlah >= minimal_grosir1 && jumlah < minimal_grosir2) {
     var harga = grosir1;
   } else if(jumlah >= minimal_grosir2 && jumlah < minimal_grosir3) {
     var harga = grosir2;
   } else if(jumlah >= minimal_grosir3) {
     var harga = grosir3;
   };

   var total = jumlah * harga;
   $("#satuanbarang").val(satuan); 
   $("#hargabarang").val(harga); 
       $("#totalharga").val(total); 
     }); 
   });

 </script>
```

I want it to look like green, but without having to highlight it

[image]

Pplease help, thank you

Comment: It depend on how you are loading this value in the that input. Can you please share your JS or relevant code to this.

Comment: okay, I've added it in the description